# Any Games Engine for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, opengl, directx, game-engine

I want to create a game in Delphi

Is there any good game engine for Delphi?

based on directx 10 or OpenGL?

I need it for 3D games, or can I only do that with C++?

Comment: Have no idea how good it is, if you like take a look at http://www.casteng.com/

Comment: It is very easy to write high-performance OpenGL applications in Delphi -- I have written quite a few myself. I am not aware of any true *game engines*, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very, very broad question, and it's hard to give a simple answer.

Most "game engines" are systems that come pre-built in one language or another and implement all the low-level game logic for a certain type of game.  They generally come with some sort of toolkit that allows you to create game content (levels, characters, scripts, etc) to run on the engine.  If you're looking for a real game engine, it won't be "for Delphi."  It might have a scripting system built in, but that will be in a scripting language, not a real, compiled-to-native-code programming language like Delphi.  Probably the closest thing you'll find is the [TURBU engine](http://www.turbu-rpg.com), a work-in-progress that I'm building.  It's an engine for console-style RPGs, and it comes with Object Pascal-based scripting built in.  But it's still a scripting language with a lot of limitations, not full-fledged Delphi programming.

On the other hand, if you're looking for tools to build the game logic yourself, you can definitely find that in Delphi.  Take a look at [Asphyre](http://www.afterwarp.net/), which is a game development framework, not a game engine.  It contains a bunch of classes and units that greatly simplify the interface to the multimedia components on a computer, such as DirectX/OpenGL, keyboard, mouse and other inputs, sound and music, etc.  It's a fairly good framework, suitable for building a game engine in.  It doesn't come with any components for scripting, but there are a fair number of scripting languages available for Delphi.

Hopefully this can help you get started.  If you have more specific questions, feel free to ask them here on StackOverflow, and maybe one of us can find a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the list of Games Related Delphi Links.

- [Turbu](http://turbu-rpg.com/) The Ultimate Rpg BUilder
- [AfterWarp (Asphyre Sphinx)](http://www.afterwarp.net/)
- [GLScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage)  (OpenGL Library for Delphi)
- [Various mostly 2D Games in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/gameprogramming/Game_Programming.htm) (Many Old links)

(Feel free to add to this list)

Comment: I can't help but wonder how current that delphi.about.com link is. It's got a WinG sprite kit listed. AFAIK WinG has been deprecated for at least ten years...

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Andorra 2D](http://andorra.sourceforge.net/).
It is a great engine to create games and it is more powerful than DelphiX.
I know it is called Andorra **2D**, but you can develop 3D games with it as well.
BTW there are a lot of tutorials out there, so I think there will be no problem for you to develop your game.

Update: Great tutorials for Andorra2D you can find [here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/81314-andorra-2d-ver-0-4-5-1-31-12-08-a.html).

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

there are  [unDelphiX](http://www.micrel.cz/Dx/)

but it's mostly for 2D games and based on DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Delphi OpenGL game engine under development called [Rage 3D](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rage-engine/).  It was looking promising for a while, but it doesn't seem to have been updated in 4 years.

Answer (score -1):

There was a directX wrapper project a few years ago called DelphiX.

I don't know much about the project's quality and if it was maintained over the year, but I guess you could take a look at it. (Or someone else can comment on it)

Answer (score -1):

I have been programming games in Delphi since it came out.  I use TGraphics32 extensively for the game board rendering, UndelphiX for DirectX sound and lan play, a skinning package from KSDev to give a cool look, and a multitude of general components like LMD Tools and TMS to supply special purpose functionality.  That way I can concentrate on writing the game stuff and not the tools stuff.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another good one: https://github.com/Cooler2/ApusGameEngine

Astral Heroes game was developed using this.